# R and lubridate: What is the best way to output datetime without time zone?

Tags: r, datetime, format, timezone, lubridate

I want to output a datetime in R using [lubridate](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/)'s `as_datetime()` function, but without the timezone in the end. The input is a UNIX timestamp in UTC with a timezone difference added to it.

Here's my code:

```
library(lubridate)

datetime_utc = 1665031112
timezone_difference = -14400

print(
  format(
    as_datetime(datetime_utc + timezone_difference),
    "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
  )
)

# TBD: Only working when as_datetime() is a string?
# as_datetime(datetime_utc + timezone_difference, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

According do the [documentation](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/as_date.html), the format argument can only be used when `as_datetime()` takes a string as input. But for what reason? Shouldn't it be possible to format the output even for numeric inputs?

Or is there even another more elegant way to output a datetime without timezone using lubridate?

Thanks for your help and advice!

Comment: You can only use the `format=` *argument* when the *input* to `as_datetime()` is a character, like `as_datetime("2022-01-01", format="%Y-%m-%d")`. You can use the `format()` function on any date/time (POSIXct/lt) if it already exists. Your code `format(as_datetime(datetime_utc + timezone_difference), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` works just fine.

Comment: Thank you! I was just not sure if that's the best solution. But your comment confirms that it is.